# How to allocate a fix percentage height for different div in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a title div, a content div and a footer div.

```
<div id="header">
   Title
</div>
<div id="content" style="background:red">
       <p>TEST</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
   footer
</div>
```

How can I always set the title div to be 20%, content to be 70% div and the footer to be 10%?

Thanks

Comment: You said width, but your elements are stacked.  Do you mean height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working example on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/axudak).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="header" style="background:blue">
        Title
      </div>
      <div id="content" style="background:red">
        <p>TEST</p>
      </div>
      <div id="footer" style="background:gray">
        footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body,
.container {
   height: 100%;
}

#header {
   height: 20%;
}

#content {
   height: 70%;
}

#footer {
   height: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with absolute positioning:

```
#header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 20%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  height: 70%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; 
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  height: 10%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

See [JSFiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/uGyaW/) for it in action.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/9gHY4/2/

```
#header {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    height: 70%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
```